# How to Better Parse CSV file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a `CSV` data Sheet and want to parse and filter the data out it, While working on a code I found a similar code someone has asked on [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533780/pandas-convert-the-unique-column-value-as-a-column-name-and-place-all-relating-s) there and the author having almost the same H/W data as I see that related to HPE H/W where I have some data and columns are different.

I've Just raised this question to know how we can define this code in a better and performant way.
Any help will be much appreciated.

### Sample Data:

```
Status  Server  Server Name Bay #   Model   Processor   Proc. Count Memory  Serial Number   State   Power State iLO FW  Firmware    Appliance Name
Critical    enc2010, bay 1  tdm2066.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101N9  Unmanaged   On  2.53 May 03 2017    I36 v2.40 (02/17/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  enc1011, bay 1  tdm1068.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101P6  Monitored   On  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.74 (07/21/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  enc1012, bay 1  tdm1083.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101NX  Monitored   On  2.61 Jul 27 2018    I36 v2.60 (05/21/2018)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC2004, bay 1  tdm2033.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262602L2  Monitored   On  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC2006, bay 1  vds2009 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M263604ZZ  Monitored   On  2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.20 (05/05/2016)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC2011, bay 1  tdm2081.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M2708027Z  Monitored   On  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC1003, bay 1  tdm1024.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262602KW  Monitored   On  2.73 Feb 11 2020    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC1006, bay 1  vds1009 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262505V5  Monitored   On  2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.00 (12/28/2015)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC1007, bay 1  vds1023 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M264800TR  Monitored   On  2.50 Sep 23 2016    I36 v2.30 (09/12/2016)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
```

### How Data-Frame Looks Like:

```
   Server Name         Appliance Name     Bay Enclosure
0      tdm2066  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2010
1      tdm1068  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1011
2      tdm1083  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1012
3      tdm2033  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2004
4      vds2009  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2006
5      tdm2081  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2011
6      tdm1024  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1003
7      vds1009  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1006
8      vds1023  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1007
9      vds0003  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENT0003
10     tdm7123  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC7003
 --------------- stripped lines ----------------------
```

### Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("testcreate.csv", sep="\t")
df = df[[ 'Server', 'Server Name', 'Bay #',  'Appliance Name']]    
df['Bay'] = df['Server'].str.split(',').str[1].str.lower()
df['Enclosure'] = df['Server'].str.split(',').str[0].str.upper()
df['Server Name'] = df['Server Name'].str.split('.').str[0]
df = df.drop(['Server', 'Bay #'], axis=1)
df = df[df['Appliance Name'].str.contains('C7000')]
df = pd.concat([g.set_index('Bay')['Server Name'].rename(f'{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Enclosure')],  axis=1, sort=False)
```

The above code works for me and outputs the below result but looking t learn the right way of writing from the experts.

### Returned Sample Result:  This works.

```
        ENC1002 ENC1003 ENC1005
bay 1   tdm1012 tdm1024 vds1001
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote; this seems fine to me

Comment: @Reinderien, thanks for the Support, I see this behavior quite often, without any reason down-voting a post.

Comment: One immediate improvement I see `df = pd.read_csv("testcreate.csv", sep="\t", usecols=['Server', 'Server Name',  'Appliance Name'])` where you can pick only the columns which you desired.